# How to add to a database from a web application?

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to add to a database from a spring web application. the web app has a simple jsp page where the user can enter details and then hit the submit button. once the button is clicked the results should appear in a refreshed database. I have written the basic java classes such as the one that contains the SQL statement that inserts into the particular database. I am just not sure how to link the submit button to the particular java class that adds to the database.

WebController.java

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/addQuestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addQuestion(@RequestParam(value="question", required = true)  String theQuestion , @RequestParam(value=" questionId", required = true)  Integer questionId, @RequestParam(value="category", required = true)   String category) throws SQLException{
                ViewController viewController = new ViewController();
                viewController.createQuestion(questionId, theQuestion, category, 
                return "qFour";
        }
```

ViewController.java

```
public Question createQuestion(int questionId, String theQuestion, String category, String correctAnswer) throws SQLException{
        Question question = questionController.addQuestion(questionId, theQuestion, category, correctAnswer);
        return question;
    }
```

QuestionController.java

```
public Question addQuestion(int questionId, String theQuestion, String category, String correctAnswer)throws SQLException{

       Question question = questionFactory.createQuestion();
       question.setQuestionId(questionId);
       question.setTheQuestion(theQuestion);
       question.setCategory(category);
       question.setCorrectAnswer(correctAnswer);

       qdao.addQuestion(questionId, theQuestion, category, correctAnswer);


       return question;
   }
```

QuestionsDAO.java

```
public void addQuestion(int questionID, String question, String category, String correctAnswer)throws SQLException{

        Connection connection = connFactory.getConnection();
        String query = "INSERT INTO es_rm_questions (questionID, question, category, correctAnswer) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement prepState = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        prepState.setInt(1, questionID);
        prepState.setString(2, question);
        prepState.setString(3, category);
        prepState.setString(4, correctAnswer);

        int numberOfRowsUpdated = prepState.executeUpdate();
        prepState.close();
        connection.close();
    }
```

qOne.jsp

```
<form:form method="GET" action="addQuestion">

    <input type="text" name="questionId" value="">Enter Id<br>
    <input type="text" name="theQuestion" value="">Enter Q <br>
    <input type="text" name="category" value="">Enter Category<br>
    <input type="text" name="correctAnswer" value="">Enter correct answer<br>
             <input type="submit" value="Next" >
</form:form>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
       <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

Comment: Show us the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Next line bind POST request to a path YOUAPPCONTEXT/addQuestion

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addQuestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

so you simply submit the form to specified path,
but you have no params in your method. For example if your form has input fields named question,category,questionId you should define your method as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addQuestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addQuestion(@RequestParam(value="question", required = true)  String theQuestion , @RequestParam(value=" questionId", required = true)  Integer questionId, @RequestParam(value="category", required = true)   String category) throws SQLException{
                ViewController viewController = new ViewController();
                viewController.createQuestion(questionId, theQuestion, category, 
                return "qFour";
        }
```

Comment: have edited my code in the comments to match this, running it but getting a 404. any idea? or need to see more code?

Comment: you have form:form method="GET" but you should have form:form method="POST"

Comment: i have changed that but am still getting a 404 in the browser

Comment: i've done exactly as instructed above but what happens is, when i click submit it does not return qFour but rather returns addQuestion (i.e. the page it is currently on) and so it wipes out all the current inputs. do you know why? or what i've done wrong?